# Hide/show elements of form when input checked

Tags: javascript

I currently have a html form (generated by php) with multiple instances of the following structure:

```js
function show(elem, show){
    var elements = 
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
     if(show){
      elements[i].style.display = "initial";
     }
     else{
      elements[i].style.display = "none";
     }
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Something</legend>

    <ul>
     <li>
         <input type="radio" name="X" value="No" onchange="show(this, false)">
         <label>No</label>
     </li>
     <li>
         <input type="radio" name="X" value="Yes" onchange="show(this, true)">
         <label>Yes</label>
     </li>
    </ul>
 
 <p class="hidden">
     Elements
    </p>

    <fieldset class="hidden">
     Elements
    </fieldset>

</fieldset>
```

The objective is to have the `class="hidden"` elements show when Yes is checked and hide when No is checked, and be hidden by default.

The problem is that now the status of the form is loaded from a database and "Yes" can be checked on load (in said case the html would be `<input type="radio" name="X" value="Yes" onchange="show(this, true)" checked>`), so I need some kind of onload (maybe through jQuery) function that will check if Yes is checked and, if so, will show the hidden elements. And I'm pretty much at a loss on how to proceed, since my web design skills are quite low.

I'm perfectly aware of the fact that my js and overall design is quite messy, so any suggestions on how to improve it would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Joey Pinto's suggestion, here's how it's been finally done (adding the following js):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var show=document.getElementsByClassName("shower");
    for(i=0;i<show.length;i++){
        if(show[i].checked){
            mostrar(show[i],true);
        }
    }
}
);
```

and of course adding `class="shower"`to the yes input of the radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this javascript snippet

```js
function show(elem, show){
    var elements = 
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
     if(show){
      elements[i].style.display = "initial";
     }
     else{
      elements[i].style.display = "none";
     }
    }
}

var yes_radio_button=document.getElementById("yes_radio");
if(yes_radio_button.checked){
 show(yes_radio_button,true);
}
else{
show(yes_radio_button,false);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Something</legend>

    <ul>
     <li>
         <input type="radio" name="X" value="No" id="no_radio" onchange="show(this, true)" checked>
         <label>No</label>
     </li>
     <li>
         <input type="radio" name="X" value="Yes" id="yes_radio" onchange="show(this, true)" >
         <label>Yes</label>
     </li>
    </ul>
 
 <p class="hidden">
     Elements
    </p>

    <fieldset class="hidden">
     Elements
    </fieldset>

</fieldset>
```

Try the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9zgfjrub/)

Comment: It's a good idea, but there are multiple instances of that same structure troughout the form, and usign a different id for each one of them would be excessive; is there a way of doing the same by having a loop check every "show" class and then doing the same action?

Comment: Yeah that could be handled by using class names instead of id. You'll need to fetch the radio button by class name and use the same logic

Comment: Took me a while due to my unfamiliarity with js, but your suggestion worked as a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS only if you use checkbox.
Use the `:checked` selector to display the content.

```
// You css 
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    color: #ccc;
    font-style: italic;
} 

// Set the content to be displayed when the radio/checkbox is checked.
// using the css3 selector :checked
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: #f00;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm"> 
<label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the same class name to everyone of your `<fieldset>` and then loop over all elements having this class name. This loop would be executed once the page is load and on every checkbox event.

Comment: The form is quite long, so having to recheck every single radio on every update of any of them would be a bit overkill, I believe. Unless I'm not understanding your answer correctly.

Comment: You're right. @CodeWizard answer is easier and more efficient.